# full page .js prevent short scrolling on mobile

Tags: iphone, mobile, scroll, fullpage.js

Site in question: http://pizza.tgihost2.com

I'm using fullpage.js to display two food menus. There is one section with two slides. Each slide is its own food menu. The fullpage section is set to display: none at first. The fullpage section is revealed by the user via jquery.:

```
$('#launchPizzaMenu, .launch-menu').click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('noscroll');
    $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('menu', 0);
    $('#fullpage').slideDown(200);
});
```

The issue is the scrolling behavior on mobile when viewing the fullpage content. It's not smooth and fluid liek the rest of the page. When I scroll / flick, I'd expect it to continue to scroll a bit after I release my finger from the screen, but the scroll stops immediately and feels laborious to scroll through the fullpage content.

Here's my fullpage config:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['menu'],
    controlArrows: false,
    autoScrolling: false,
    responsiveWidth: 900,
    afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){

    }
});
```

Here's a gist showing the fullpage markup: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0f8c33a2a875040edb7d5503238f8f71

There is one section with two slides.
Slide one starts on line 21.
Slide two starts on 152

How can I achieve smooth scrolling within the fullpage content?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the fullPage.js option `scrollOverflow:true` instead of your own `overflow: scroll;` for the section with bigger content.

See [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

The smooth scrolling won't work as expected in all devices/browsers unless you use a library like iScroll.js, which is the one fullPage.js uses when using `scrollOverflow:true`.